# Android: Facebook: How to ask user for required permission

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to Facebook login steps policy (to get the application approved), do I have to show the user a dialog (with yes and no buttons) explaining the required permission (ex: user_likes) or I can just call

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(...)
```

which will open the Facebook grant permission dialog with required permission(s)?

Same thing, when user opens my app and select a feature that requires to log in, do I call directly

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(public_profile)
```

or do I have to show a confirmation dialog first?

[image]

Comment: are you asking if you have to create your own dialog explaining the permissions?

Comment: Yes, do I have to ask the user for the permission before using the function above which will of course open Facebook grant permission dialog?

Comment: Are you using the built in login button? It should automatically prompt the user to accept the set permissions at login. You dont have to ask every time they use a feature

Comment: No, I don't use the login button, I use logInWithReadPermissions(..), I made an edit with the picture recommended (as an example) by Facebook, that's why I'm asking. For me I check only if getAccessToken(...) is null and shows the user a dialog as in the picture to ask him to sign in, but do I have to show the same dialog as in the pic above everytime I ask for new permission? (I don't ask for all needed permissions as once, I ask for the permission required for specific task / job as recommended by Facebook), Am I right so far?

Comment: I would not have the user sign in multiple times every time they want to use a new feature.

Comment: Same thing came into my mind about signing it, but what about asking for permissions, where I ask for needed permission when based on user selection of one of my application features, do I show him another dialog like the one above saying for example "You need to grant application user_likes to use this feature" or it's just enough to call the API with user_likes permission where Facebook will show a dialog asking for the permission with [ OK - Cancel ] options? What do you think?

Comment: BTW, once I get your last answer, you can collect your comments in one answer to select it as accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: the function logInWithReadPermissions will automatically create a dialog box asking for permissions.  You do not need to ask for "public_profile" since it is automatic, but whatever permissions you ask for will show up in the automatically generated dialog box.  You do not need to specifically generate your own dialog at all.

Comment: @user3268305 Thank you so much for your answer, but I believe that I at least have to provide 'Sign in dialog' as in the picture above, when the user uses my application for the first time and uses one of my application features that requires signing in with at least public_profile permission, am I right? and what do you think?

Comment: That depends on your app. Facebook policy does not require a dialog at all. The Facebook sign-in dialog is pretty descriptive as to what the user is doing. If you think the user would be confused as to why they're seeing the Facebook dialog box, it makes sense to include your own UI feature to smooth the experience. Based on the screenshots, it looks like Facebook login is activating from a toggle switch. As a user, I think the additional dialog probably makes sense. But, that's another step the user has to click through to activate the feature, so you'll have to weigh the pros and cons. =)

Comment: Again thank you for sharing your opinion, you've been very helpful :) I believe you should collect them as an answer to be accepted and rated ... And I really wonder why I got -1 for my question, what's wrong about it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to create your own custom dialog to display to the user when they are signing in with Facebook or using a feature which requires Facebook permission. Facebook will automatically prompt the user to accept the set permissions when they originally log in if you are using

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(...)
```

If you want to add custom dialogs to alert the user that is okay, however I think this may make the app more tedious to use.